# Как включить bluetooth в bios и можно ли это вообще сделать

Tags: bluetooth, bios, asus

У меня bluetooth клавиатура, и я не могу с неё зайти в биос. Благо материнка от ASUS  и в биосе работает мышка, не подскажите какую функцию нужно включить чтоб клавиатура заработала в биосе? (Как  я понимаю нужно сделать так чтоб блутуз включался до загрузки системы). Если что у меня не адаптер, а встроенная в материнку антена. (Мать называет ASUS b550 E Wifi). Я если честно сам не знаю как это сделать, надеюсь вы поможете.

Comment: На некоторых клавиатурах есть rf пупок в комплекте. Через него работает

Answer (score 0):

Честно, я не знаю что тут не понятного и зачем я вообще это спрашивал.

Короче нет - нельзя, потому что драйвера с блютузом загружаются при включении OS, в биосе данная функция должна быть прописана разработчиками.